# PHP cURL & Blackboard Learn - Data is not correct.... POX Data Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: php, xml, curl, oauth, blackboard

When I try to POST this XML document to Blackboard Learn LIS using PHP cURL I get this error. I'm checking the XML with simplexml to ensure it is well formed, so that's not the issue.  I have also checked the XML document to ensure there is no BOM data attached.  I've opened it in a Hex editor to ensure this.

I'm completely stumped on this one and I don't have access to the Blackboard logs.

PHP:

```
include("xml/envelope.php");

//sanity check to see if xml is well formed
    $sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $xml = $sxml->asXML();

    $xml_length = strlen($xml);

    $url = $this->lis_outcome_service_url;

    $bodyHash = base64_encode(sha1($xml, TRUE)); // build oauth_body_hash
    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($key, $secret);
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, '', 'POST', $url, array('oauth_body_hash' => $bodyHash) );
    $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, '');
    $header = $request->to_header() . "Content-Type: application/xml\r\nContent-Length: $xml_length\r\n"; // add content type header

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $output .= "$url<br><br>$output<pre>$header\n\n".htmlspecialchars($xml)."</pre><p>ERRORS?: ".curl_error($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);// "<p>Saved grade: "+var_export($output)+"</p>";
    return $output;
```

The XML in envelope.php:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imsx_POXEnvelopeRequest xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/ltiv1p1/xsd/imsoms_v1p0">
    <imsx_POXHeader>
            <imsx_POXRequestHeaderInfo>
                    <imsx_version>V1.0</imsx_version>
                    <imsx_messageIdentifier>$id</imsx_messageIdentifier>
            </imsx_POXRequestHeaderInfo>
    </imsx_POXHeader>
    <imsx_POXBody>
            <replaceResultRequest>
                    <resultRecord>
                            <sourcedGUID>
                                    <sourcedId>$this->lis_result_sourcedid</sourcedId>
                            </sourcedGUID>
                            <result>
                                    <resultScore>
                                            <language>en-us</language>
                                            <textString>0.7</textString>
                                    </resultScore>
                            </result>
                    </resultRecord>
            </replaceResultRequest>
    </imsx_POXBody>
</imsx_POXEnvelopeRequest>
XML;
?>
```

The XML output in browser after parsing (during cURL request):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imsx_POXEnvelopeRequest xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/ltiv1p1/xsd/imsoms_v1p0">
    <imsx_POXHeader>
            <imsx_POXRequestHeaderInfo>
                    <imsx_version>V1.0</imsx_version>
                    <imsx_messageIdentifier>53e4657ec1499</imsx_messageIdentifier>
            </imsx_POXRequestHeaderInfo>
    </imsx_POXHeader>
    <imsx_POXBody>
            <replaceResultRequest>
                    <resultRecord>
                            <sourcedGUID>
                                    <sourcedId>bbgc15659375gi290156</sourcedId>
                            </sourcedGUID>
                            <result>
                                    <resultScore>
                                            <language>en-us</language>
                                            <textString>0.7</textString>
                                    </resultScore>
                            </result>
                    </resultRecord>
            </replaceResultRequest>
    </imsx_POXBody>
</imsx_POXEnvelopeRequest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is so little detailed information on how to do this in LTI, I've posted my solution below.  This is a duplicate of my addition to Blackboard's EduGarage forums, but to get it into the public domain I've put it here.  I hope it helps other people trying to implement LTI tools.

Here is how to pass back a grade using PHP cURL, the contents of the envelope.php file should
follow the XML found in the [IMS Global Documentation found here](http://www.imsglobal.org/LTI/v1p1/ltiIMGv1p1.html#_Toc319560469).  The cURL request constructs the header and then adds the XML body below it. 
Note that the envelope.php file contains the $xml variable in the following format (you will obviously need to add your own $id and set a grade with a variable etc...):

[image: POX XML in PHP for replacing user grade in LMS]

PHP code for passing grade using cURL:

```
include("xml/envelope.php");

        $xml_length = strlen($xml);

        $url = $this->lis_outcome_service_url;

        $bodyHash = base64_encode(sha1($xml, TRUE)); // build oauth_body_hash
        $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($key, $secret);
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, '', 'POST', $url, array('oauth_body_hash' => $bodyHash) );
        $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, '');
        $header .= $request->to_header(); // add content type header

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("POST http://your-tools-url-here.edu.au HTTP/1.0",
                                                    "Content-Length: $xml_length", $header, "Content-Type: application/xml"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```